# ByRef argument type mismatch in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with VBA. I wrote a user define function that takes a `string`, process it and return a cleaned `string`. I am not sure what is wrong with it. I am not able to call it and ask it to process my string and return it. I am thinking there are a mistake in the way I am defining or returning it.

```
Public Function ProcessString(input_string As String) As String
    ' The temp string used throughout the function
    Dim temp_string As String

    For i = 1 To Len(input_string)
        temp_string = Mid(input_string, i, 1)
        If temp_string Like "[A-Z, a-z, 0-9, :, -]" Then
            return_string = return_string & temp_string
        End If
    Next i
    return_string = Mid(return_string, 1, (Len(return_string) - 1))
    ProcessString = return_string & ", "
End Function
```

And I use this function like this

```
Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(last_name)
```

Last name is a string variable, usually looks like this `Lastname*****`, and I am trying to remove all the stars behind it. Have it return `Lastname` without the stars.

I received `Compile error: ByRef arugment type mismatch` when I tried to run this. I am using Windows XP with Office 2003.

EDIT: I added the basic struction of the code I have, I have about 20 lines of the similar code. Doing the same thing for each field I need.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
' In my original production code I have a chain of these
' Like this Dim last_name, first_name, street, apt, city, state, zip As String
Dim last_name As String

' I get the last name from a fixed position of my file. Because I am 
' processing it from another source which I copied and pasted into excel
last_name = Mid(Range("A4").Value, 20, 13)

' Insert the data into the corresponding fields in the database worksheet
Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(last_name)
```

Comment: On which line does the error flag?

Comment: It flaged on the line when I call it. `Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(last_name)`

Comment: Microsoft says to double the parentheses around the offending variable, so Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString((last_name))

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I suspect you haven't set up `last_name` properly in the caller.

With the statement `Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(last_name)`

this will only work if `last_name` is a string, i.e.

```
Dim last_name as String
```

appears in the caller somewhere.

**The reason for this is that VBA passes in variables *by reference* by default which means that the data types have to match exactly between caller and callee.**

### Two fixes:

1) **Force ByVal** -- Change your function to pass variable ByVal: 
`Public Function ProcessString(ByVal input_string As String) As String`, or

2) **Dim varname** -- put `Dim last_name As String` in the caller before you use it.

(1) works because for `ByVal`, a copy of input_string is taken when passing to the function which will coerce it into the correct data type. It also leads to better program stability since the function cannot modify the variable in the caller.

Comment: I always declare all my VBA functions with ByVal as it improves stability. With Java you have no choice, everything is passed by value.

Comment: This helped a lot. My argument is a variable used in the `For Each` loop, and it was not declared with `Dim`. Checking `TypeName` in runtime showed correct type, but for the compiler it was, perhaps, `Variant`. Adding `Dim` before the loop solved the issue.

Answer (score 31):

I don't know why, but it is very important to declare the variables separately if you want to pass variables (as variables) into other procedure or function.

For example there is a procedure which make some manipulation with data: based on ID returns Part Number and Quantity information. ID as constant value, other two arguments are variables.

```
Public Sub GetPNQty(ByVal ID As String, PartNumber As String, Quantity As Long)
```

the next main code gives me a "ByRef argument mismatch":

```
Sub KittingScan()  
Dim BoxPN As String
Dim BoxQty, BoxKitQty As Long

  Call GetPNQty(InputBox("Enter ID:"), BoxPN, BoxQty) 

End sub
```

and the next one is working as well:

```
Sub KittingScan()
Dim BoxPN As String
Dim BoxQty As Long
Dim BoxKitQty As Long

  Call GetPNQty(InputBox("Enter ID:"), BoxPN, BoxQty)

End sub
```

Comment: It's not that you necessarily need to declare on separate lines here.  It's that `Dim BoxQty, BoxKitQty As Long` is implicitly declaring BoxQty as Variant.  `Dim BoxQty as Long, BoxKitQty As Long` on one line should work fine.

Comment: This solution worked for me. My calling program had

Answer (score 4):

I changed a few things to work with `Option Explicit`, and the code ran fine against a cell containing `"abc.123"`, which returned `"abc.12,"`. There were no compile errors.

```
Option Explicit ' This is new

Public Function ProcessString(input_string As String) As String
    ' The temp string used throughout the function
    Dim temp_string As String
    Dim i As Integer ' This is new
    Dim return_string As String ' This is new
    For i = 1 To Len(input_string)
        temp_string = Mid(input_string, i, 1)
        If temp_string Like "[A-Z, a-z, 0-9, :, -]" Then
            return_string = return_string & temp_string
        End If
    Next i
    return_string = Mid(return_string, 1, (Len(return_string) - 1))
    ProcessString = return_string & ", "
End Function
```

I'll suggest you post more of your relevant code (that calls this function). You've stated that last_name is a String, but it appears that may not be the case. Step through your code line by line and ensure that this is actually the case.

Comment: After I added the missed Dim statement, it prompted (highlighted) the line where I have the `Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()`, and also the `last_name` is highlighted. Very strange behaviors, my Sub is basically a buttom that do a list of things.

Answer (score 3):

While looping through your string one character at a time is a viable method, there's no need.  VBA has built-in functions for this kind of thing:

```
Public Function ProcessString(input_string As String) As String
    ProcessString=Replace(input_string,"*","")
End Function
```

Comment: That's a really good solution. But could you please show me how to fix the problem? Because I am also trying to figure out what did I do wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem here was that I was declaring multiple variables in a row instead of separate rows.

For example, I was trying to pass i as an integer to my function.

```
Dim i,j as integer - gets me the error
Dim i as integer - doesn't get the error
```

Comment: This just repeats the existing answers from 8 years prior.

Comment: @Sorcerer_ `Dim i,j as integer` declares i as Variant. You can do it with a one line declaration, you need to make sure to explicitly declare every variable in the line: `Dim i as integer, j as integer`

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with that string try like this:

```
Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(CStr(last_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ByRef needs to know the size of the parameter. A declaration of
Dim last_name as string
doesn't specify the size of the string so it takes it as an error. Before using
Worksheets(data_sheet).Range("C2").Value = ProcessString(last_name)
The last_name has to be declared as
Dim  last_name as string *10 ' size of string is up to you but must be a fix length

No need to change the function. Function doesn't take a fix length declaration.