# ByRef argument type mismatch VBA

Tags: vba

We are making a simulation of a race but we are stuck and we don't know where the problem is.

VBA gives us an error by the variable `BusPrice` and the other variables who are declared below the private sub. The code is from several modules.

```
Sub batasimulation(NumberTeams As Integer, NumberStarts As Integer, _
     TimeBetweenStarts As Integer, VanIntervalBefore As Integer, _
     VanIntervalAfter As Integer, TimeWindow As Integer, _
     CostsGeneral As Long, fee As Long, BreakfastPrice As Long, _
     BreakfastPercentage As Long, DinnerPrice As Long, _
     DinnerPercentage As Long, BusPrice As Double, _
     NumberTrajects As Integer, CostsBoardPersonal As Long, _
     CostsTeam As Long, CostsRestart As Long)
    '
    'this procedure simulates one bata race and determines the crowdedness at each node

    'Define the worksheets
    Dim LT, SP, ED, ST, KNP As Worksheet
    Set LT = Sheets("SimRunningtimes")
    Set SP = Sheets("StatTeams")
    Set ED = Sheets("StageData")
    Set ST = Sheets("SimStartTimes")
    Set KNP = Sheets("SimNodes")
    'aux variables
    Dim stage As Integer 'counters

    'disable updating the screen, speeds up code execution
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LT.Cells.ClearContents
    ST.Cells.ClearContents
    LT.UsedRange 'dim sheet the size of used data, speeds up code
    ST.UsedRange
    'create headers in sheets SimRunningtimes and SimStartTimes
    LT.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Teamtype"
    ST.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Startgroup"
    For stage = 1 To 25
        LT.Cells(stage + 2, 1) = "stage " & stage
        ST.Cells(stage + 2, 1) = "stage " & stage
    Next stage

    Call SimulateRunningTimes(NumberTeams) 'simulate running times(Q3)
    Call DetermineStartTimes(NumberTeams, NumberStarts, TimeBetweenStarts) 'determine starttimes per stage (Q4)
    Call nodes(TimeWindow, NumberTeams, VanIntervalBefore, VanIntervalAfter) ''determine crowdedness at nodes
    Call registration(NumberTeams, fee, BreakfastPrice, BreakfastPercentage, DinnerPrice, DinnerPercentage, BusPrice, NumberTrajects, CostsBoardPersonal, CostsTeam, CostsGeneral, CostsRestart)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub registration(NumberTeams As Integer, CostsGeneral As Long, fee As Long, BreakfastPrice As Long, BreakfastPercentage As Long, DinnerPrice As Long, DinnerPercentage As Integer, BusPrice As Double, NumberTrajects As Integer, CostsBoardPersonal As Long, CostsTeam As Long, CostsRestart As Long)
    Dim BU As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set BU = Sheets("budget")

    BU.Cells(6, 10) = NumberTeams * CDbl(fee)
    BU.Cells(20, 10) = NumberTeams * 24.34
    BU.Cells(21, 10) = NumberTeams * CDbl(BusPrice) * CDbl(NumberTrajects)
    BU.Cells(22, 10) = NumberTeams * CDbl(DinnerPrice) * CDbl(DinnerPercentage)
    BU.Cells(23, 10) = NumberTeams * CDbl(BreakfastPrice) * CDbl(BreakfastPercentage)

    BU.Cells(31, 10) = NumberTeams * 77.92
    BU.Cells(32, 10) = NumberTeams * 92.3
    BU.Cells(33, 10) = 43081 + (NumberStarts * 5000)
    BU.Cells(38, 10) = NumberTeams * 97.39
    BU.Cells(39, 10) = NumberTeams * 47.86
    BU.Cells(40, 10) = NumberTeams * 22.02

    BU.Cells(25, 10) = 0
    For i = 6 To 23
        BU.Cells(25, 10) = BU.Cells(25, 10) + BU.Cells(i, 10)
    Next i

    BU.Cells(43, 10) = 0
    For i = 29 To 40
        BU.Cells(43, 10) = BU.Cells(43, 10) + BU.Cells(i, 10)
    Next i

    BU.Cells(46, 10) = BU.Cells(25, 10) - BU.Cells(43, 10)
End Sub

Private Sub SimulateBtn_Click()
    Dim NumberSimulations As Integer
    Dim NumberTeams As Integer
    Dim NumberStarts As Integer
    Dim NumberRestarts As Integer
    Dim TimeBetweenStarts As Integer
    Dim TimeWindow As Integer
    Dim VanIntervalBefore As Integer
    Dim VanIntervalAfter As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim ED As Worksheet
    Dim fee As Long
    Dim BreakfastPrice As Long
    Dim BreakfastPercentage As Long
    Dim DinnerPrice As Long
    Dim DinnerPercentage As Long
    Dim BusPrice As Double
    Dim NumberTrajects As Integer
    Dim CostsBoardPersonal As Long
    Dim CostsTeam As Long
    Dim CostsGeneral As Long
    Dim CostsRestarts As Long

    For s = 1 To NumberSimulations
        Call batasimulation(NumberTeams, NumberRestarts, TimeBetweenStarts, VanIntervalBefore, VanIntervalAfter, TimeWindow, CostsGeneral, fee, BreakfastPrice, BreakfastPercentage, DinnerPrice, DinnerPercentage, BusPrice, NumberTrajects, CostsBoardPersonal, CostsTeam, CostsRestarts)
        Call CalculateKPI
    Next s
```

Comment: Try adding `ByVal` in front of each parameter name like this: `Sub batasimulation(ByVal NumberTeams As Integer, ByVal ...`.

Comment: In the first procedure you are not declaring your variables, maybe that could be the problem.

Comment: You forgot to pass `CostsGeneral` to `registration()`, so all your arguments are off by one which naturally results in [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16611547/11683).

Comment: Instead of posting the full code listing, please always try to reduce the code to the minimum required to produce the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Adding ByVal worked. Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB, if you don't specify, by default your parameters will be passed by reference. You must always use `ByVal` for all parameters except when you really want to pass some parameters by reference. Even then, I recommend that you use `ByRef` for clarity.

Add `ByVal` in front of each parameter name in your `batasimulation` sub-routine like this:

```
Sub registration(ByVal NumberTeams As Integer, ByVal CostsGeneral As Long, ByVal fee As Long, ByVal BreakfastPrice As Long, ByVal BreakfastPercentage As Long, ByVal DinnerPrice As Long, ByVal DinnerPercentage As Integer, ByVal BusPrice As Double, ByVal NumberTrajects As Integer, ByVal CostsBoardPersonal As Long, ByVal CostsTeam As Long, ByVal CostsRestart As Long)
```