# Passing 2 range variables to a Sub - Object required/ByRef argument Type mismatch error

Tags: vba

I am trying to copy range from 1 worksheet with conditional formatting rules and paste in another workbook using the exact formatting but deleting the conditional rules.
I am passing 2 range objects to my sub and when calling the macro I am getting the error. Please help me.

```
  Sub Create() 
  Dim rgFrom, rgTo As Range
  oldBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  Workbooks.Add
  Set rgFrom = Workbooks("Daily Flow Template.xlsm").Worksheets("DailyFlow").Range("A1:BZ110")
  Set rgTo = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BZ110")
  PasteFormattedRange (rgFrom), rgTo   ----- Error Object Required
  End Sub

  Sub PasteFormattedRange(ByRef rgFrom As Range, ByRef rgTo As Range)
   Dim S                     As String
   Dim rgStart As Range
   Dim i As Long, CF_Format  As Long
   Dim SaveDisplayAlerts As Boolean, SaveScreenUpdating As Boolean
   Dim HTMLInClipBoard       As Boolean
   Dim Handle As Long, Ptr As Long, FileName As String
   Set rgStart = Selection
   rgFrom.Copy

'Enumerate the clipboard formats
  If OpenClipboard(0) Then
    CF_Format = EnumClipboardFormats(0&)
    Do While CF_Format <> 0
        S = String(255, vbNullChar)
        i = GetClipboardFormatName(CF_Format, S, 255)
        S = Left(S, i)
        HTMLInClipBoard = InStr(1, S, "HTML Format", vbTextCompare) > 0
        If HTMLInClipBoard Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.Goto rgTo
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"
            Application.Goto rgStart
            Exit Do
        End If
        CF_Format = EnumClipboardFormats(CF_Format)
    Loop
    CloseClipboard
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I am not using paranthesis, I am getting "ByRef argument type mismatch" .  PasteFormattedRange rgFrom, rgTo

Comment: Try `Dim rgFrom As Range, rgTo As Range` - [This Answer about "ByRef Argument Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612000/9663006) might help to better understand - It *may* be best to change to `ByVal` rather than `ByRef` but someone with a better understanding should really explain this/why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ByRef argument type mismatch

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611547/byref-argument-type-mismatch-in-excel-vba/16612000#16612000) from "[ByRef argument type mismatch in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611547/byref-argument-type-mismatch-in-excel-vba)" might help explain this error a bit clearer than I can.

The basic gist of it is:

- Unless you need to, pass arguments `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`.
- If you use `ByRef` make sure to declare your statements explicitly rather than delcaring with the default data type (`Variant`) that way you will be passing a `Range` where a `Range` is expected.

[This answer on my question on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/216179) also touches on passing arguments `ByVal` opposed to `ByRef`.

---

### Object required (Error 424)

If you are not returning a value, you don't need to include *parentheses* `( )` - You can read about it on [Using parentheses in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code)(VBA).

The below edit to your problem line will execute without the `Object Required` error:

```
PasteFormattedRange rgFrom, rgTo
```

---

When using parentheses for a `Sub`, `Function` or any other `Method` or `Property`, you would need to encapsulate all arguments within the parentheses rather than just one ***if the parentheses are actually required***.

If you are assigning a value, you would need the parentheses, like so:

```
Sub Foo()
    x = MyFunction(Argument1, Argument2)
End Sub
```

If you are not assigning a value, you don't include the parentheses, like so:

```
Sub Foo()
    MySub Argument1, Argument2
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add, calling a Sub and enclosing its arguments in brackets *forces* them to be passed `ByVal` which sometimes is not appropriate.